# SQL Server 2008R2 - BAK file backup performance issue

Tags: performance, backup

Just note I'm not a DBA or anything close to that.

**Problem:**

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2. We have 32 databases and backup to local disk (3PAR) using SQL Server maintenance plan. Normally it takes 8 hours for 950 GB. few days ago backup took over 25 hours with transfer rate of 25 MB/Sec. Normally it is minimum 130 MB/Sec. Now I'm trying to troubleshot if is is a IO issue or something wrong with the DB server or the databases.

I have done some manual backup testing on a 52 GB databases and the test results are mix.

- Backup start to finish as normal with average transfer rate 150 MB/Sec (total 8 mins)
- Backup is really quick in start and then slows down, first 20 % of the backup with 250MB/sec then can slow down to 25 MB/Sec (35 Mins)
- Backup start slow with 25mb/sec (35 Minx)

Troubleshooting steps that I have done

Server environment

- No Antivirus or 3rd party tool running in the background
- No updates done on the OS

Disk

- No changes with the Database F disk (2TB with 240 GB free)
- No Changes with the backup Z disk (2TB)

SQL server

- No changes

Ran those following SQL command during the slow backup performance

Command 1

```
Select session_id,command, percent_complete 
From sys.dm_exec_requests
```

Finding: no fault found

Command 2

```
SELECT * FROM

sys.dm_os_wait_stats 

DBCC SQLPERF ('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR);
GO
```

Finding: no fault find

Command 3

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

**Finding:**

Noticed `BACKUPTHREAD` wait time keep increasing and can get up to 3245800

Result is link below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nnsch0msr6mi54/output.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Is your server's power setting set to balanced as opposed to high performance?  Instant file initialization enabled ? Are you using backup compression?

Comment: -The power settings is correctly set as balanced 
- Backup is compressed already 
- Instant file initialization is not enabled yet but will enable and let you know the result.

Comment: Just called the offsite support team :/ they advised to do a SQL IO check so they can have some baseline before going to the storage team

Comment: I can confirm is not the IO bottle neck, After running Read and Write test on Data F drive and backup Z drive. both through is the same, during backup process and when backup is not running. Software - SQLIO Disk Subsystem Benchmark Tool

Comment: How are you measuring the transfer rate? If you are reading the rate at which data is written to the backup file than compression will cause this to vary widely - at times it could be reading barely compressible data so writing as much as it is reading and at other points it could be only needing to write 10% (% figure plucked from the air!) of the amount it reads. Also is there significant contention for CPU resource? Normally these things are IO bound but if there is a lot of CPU activity from other processes the compression work the CPU is doing can sometimes be a bottleneck too.

Comment: I would examine the storage and secondly I would want to know where that drive is located. Normally, I have seen Z drives be networked to the server. Not local, this is terrible for performance when backing up.

Comment: Z drive is on a local SAN.
During the backup the CPU is hardly getting hit. average of 13 %.

Comment: What is the best way to measure disk I/O ?
thanks for everyone's help so far